# Python: Making a recursive function that takes a list, and returns a list containing elements of the previous list but no duplicates?

Tags: python, list, recursion

Here is the non-recursive code I came up with.

```
def newlst(lst):
    new_lst = []

    for element in lst:
        if element not in new_lst:
            new_lst.append(element)

    return new_lst
```

Now here is my attempt at a recursive version:

```
def newlst(lst):
    new_lst = []

    if lst == []:
        return new_lst

    if lst[0] in new_lst:
        new_lst.append(lst[0])
    else:
        return newlst(lst[1:])
```

I'm aware that I assign newlst to an empty list value each time the function calls itself and I don't know where else to assign it... So I'm lost.

Comment: You have to carry the result with you during recursion, so your second `newlist` function is missing this argument. otoh, this is an O(n**2) way to do it -- while sorting is only O(n log n)...

Comment: Doing this with recursion is not a good idea… If this is an assignment, tell your teacher that this is a terrible exercise for learning recursion and that they should think of a better one.

Comment: You could potentially salvage the complexity of this algorithm by using the `bisect` module to do an insertion sort (instead of `append`), but that sort of obviates the need for recursion (since you'd just be traversing the list).  I agree with @poke that this is a terrible exercise for learning recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Agree this is an awful way of removing duplicates, but if you really want a recursive solution:

```
def newlst(lst):
    if not lst:
        return lst

    new_lst = newlst(lst[1:])
    return new_lst if lst[0] in new_lst else [lst[0]] + new_lst

>>> newlst([1,1,2])
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def newlst(lst):  
    if lst == []:
        new_list = []          
    elif lst[0] in lst[1:]:
        new_list = newlst(lst[1:])        
    else:
        new_list =[lst[0]]+ newlst(lst[1:])                        
    return new_list
```